# How do I call the RPC method `contractInfoOf` using curl?

Tags: polkadot-js, rpc, contracts, documentation

The [docs state](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/custom-rpcs/) that the RPC comes with a few `defaultRPCs` and then links to polkadotJS documentation on the available API calls. This doesn't help me if I want to call a method using `curl`.

Does anyone know how to call [`contractInfoOf`](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage/#contractinfoofaccountid32-optionpalletcontractsstoragerawcontractinfo) using `curl`?

I've tried `storage_contract_info_of`, `storage_contractInfoOf`, and various other combinations using `contracts` as the prefix.

e.g.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "contracts_contractInfoOf", ["5CYKEXWU3L4zWregopd2bTjoZLH9yHBpfXaqkFaTfxacaSA1"]}' http://substrate-node:9933/
```

However, none of these seem valid. I've used `grep` to look for a list of rpc calls in [substrate](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate) and I got the following:

```
> grep -rPo '#\[rpc\(name\s=\s"([A-Za-z_]*)' | sort | uniq | awk -F '"' '{print $2}'
babe_epochAuthorship
engine_createBlock
engine_finalizeBlock
grandpa_proveFinality
grandpa_roundState
author_hasKey
author_hasSessionKeys
author_insertKey
author_pendingExtrinsics
author_removeExtrinsic
author_rotateKeys
author_submitExtrinsic
chain_getBlock
chain_getBlockHash
chain_getFinalizedHead
chain_getHeader
childstate_getKeys
childstate_getKeysPaged
childstate_getStorage
childstate_getStorageEntries
childstate_getStorageHash
childstate_getStorageSize
state_getChildReadProof
offchain_localStorageGet
offchain_localStorageSet
state_call
state_getKeys
state_getKeysPaged
state_getMetadata
state_getPairs
state_getReadProof
state_getRuntimeVersion
state_getStorage
state_getStorageHash
state_getStorageSize
state_queryStorage
state_queryStorageAt
state_traceBlock
system_addLogFilter
system_addReservedPeer
system_chain
system_chainType
system_health
system_localListenAddresses
system_localPeerId
system_name
system_nodeRoles
system_peers
system_properties
system_removeReservedPeer
system_reservedPeers
system_resetLogFilter
system_syncState
system_unstable_networkState
system_version
sync_state_genSyncSpec
contracts_call
contracts_getStorage
contracts_instantiate
contracts_upload_code
mmr_generateProof
payment_queryFeeDetails
payment_queryInfo
system_accountNextIndex
system_dryRun
```

No mention of `contractInfoOf`. Where is it located and how do I call it?

Comment: curl `rpc_methods` will show you all calls exposed by the node. `contractInfoOf` is a state call, e.g. the correct storage key to `stage_getStorage`

Comment: Thanks, Jaco. Very helpful.

Comment: Is the storage key the encoded contract address? e.g. `u8aToHex(decodeAddress("5CYKEXWU3L4zWregopd2bTjoZLH9yHBpfXaqkFaTfxacaSA1"))`

Comment: It is encoded using the hasher for the map. One of the examples that show the key I can think of is the apps UI chain-state app, e.g. [Canvas on Rococo](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frococo-canvas-rpc.polkadot.io#/chainstate) has contracts, so if you navigate in that app to contracts.contractInfoOf you can see how the key is generated in the details below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reposting the answer from Jaco above, so that this question no longer shows up as one without answers.

> curl `rpc_methods` will show you all calls exposed by the node. `contractInfoOf` is a state call, e.g. the correct storage key to `state_getStorage`